# Transaction mySql. Заполнение связанных таблиц

Tags: sql, post, transaction

Всем привет.
Возникла потребность в заполнении связанных таблиц.
Примерная структура показана на фото
id - простые auto-increment

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При отправке транзакции

```
START TRANSACTION;

SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;

INSERT INTO authors(author_name) VALUE ('Vern');
SET @a = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO books(title) VALUE ('Captain');
SET @b = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO books_data(book_id, author_id) VALUES (@a, @b);

COMMIT;
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`books_tt`.`books_data`, CONSTRAINT `books_data_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`author_id`) REFERENCES `authors` (`id`))
```

Вопрос следующий. Как отправить POST запрос правильно заполнив эти 3 таблицы?

Comment: У вас `SET @a`  дважды.

Comment: @Ainar-G простите, исправил

Comment: А в коде той же ошибки нет?

Comment: @Ainar-G нет, я ошибся здесь, там все верно, но 1452 не уходит)

Comment: А запросы точно оба проходят без ошибок?  Если у вас какой-нибудь _ORM,_ может он скрывает что-то?

Comment: @Ainar-G нет, orm не юзаю., По отдельности все проходит. Может быть проблема в функции last inser id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы перепутали порядок *ID.*  Вместо:

```sql
INSERT INTO books_data (book_id, author_id) VALUES (@a, @b);
```

Должно быть:

```sql
INSERT INTO books_data (author_id, book_id) VALUES (@a, @b);
```

Comment: Спасибо, но думаю, проблема в другом

Comment: Тогда уже не знаю.

Comment: Я пробовал по разному, но ошибку все равно выдает

Comment: Да, прошу прощения, не доглядел, действительно перепутал местами параметры)